# Problems running mvn for apache-maven

Tags: apache, maven

In the image below, it says JAVA_HOME is set to an invalid directory.  However, that is where my Java folder is located.. in `C:\Program Files\Java`... I don't think it is case sensitive, right?  What would you deduce is wrong with running mvn?

Thanks for any thoughts and ideas. :)

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely java is not installed in `C:\Program Files\Java` but in `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_25` or a similar subfolder.